# Removing first and last double quotes (preferably sed/awk)

Tags: awk, sed

I only want to remove the first and last double quotes

Input:

```
word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {"word5 'word6' "word7 word8" .word9"} -word10 (word11)
word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {"word5 'word6' word7 word8 .word9"} -word10 (word11)
word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {"word5 'word6' "word7 (word8)" .word9"} -word10 (word11)
```

Expected output:

```
word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {word5 'word6' "word7 word8" .word9} -word10 (word11)
word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {word5 'word6' word7 word8 .word9} -word10 (word11)
word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {word5 'word6' "word7 (word8)" .word9} -word10 (word11)
```

Tried this to remove the first `"` but it did not work:

```
sed 's/"\({\)/\1/g' inputfile > outputfile
```

Removing the first double quote found in the line, that is after a "{" and before a "}" can be accepted.

Assuming **word** can be of different lengths too.

Comment: What about `sed 's/"\(.*\)"/\1/'`?

Comment: try this : sed 's/"\({[^}]*}\)"/\1/g' inputfile > outputfile

Comment: What if the first `"` of the line is before the first `{` of the line (and last, after, `}`, respectively)?

Comment: what if there is only one double-quote? or an odd number?

Comment: In your regexp, `/"\({\)/`, the `"` comes before the `{`. In your data the `{` comes before the `"`. Order matters in pattern matching.

Comment: @Renaud Pacalet Thanks, I am going with your answer since it is the simplest and works for my condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this sed with a capture group:

```bash
sed -E 's/\{"(.*)"}/{\1}/' file

word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {word5 'word6' "word7 word8" .word9} -word10 (word11)
word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {word5 'word6' word7 word8 .word9} -word10 (word11)
word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {word5 'word6' "word7 (word8)" .word9} -word10 (word11)
```

Here pattern `{"(.*)"}` matches longest match between `{"` and `"}` and captures test in the middle into a capture group.

Comment: FWIW you don't need to escape the `}`.

Comment: `}` is still considered a regex meta character. If I call `re.escape('{}')` in Python it gives: `\{\}` i.e. both escaped.

Comment: not in an ERE as you're using - `}` is only a metachar if it was preceded by an RE-interval opening `{`, just like `)` following `(` or not. In POSIX `\}` is undefined behavior (just like almost any other char) in any other context than that but I expect will usually be treated as literal so the ```\``` probably isn't really doing any harm. Maybe python's assuming PCRE? I've no idea what PCRE rules are.

Comment: Some supporting references for what I just said - https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_03 defines ERE "special characters" where "An ERE special character has special properties in certain contexts. Outside those contexts, or when preceded by a <backslash>, such a character shall be an ERE that matches the special character itself.". So "special characters" are made literal by preceding with a backslash but note that the list does not include `}` so `}` is not a "special character" therefore it's an "ordinary character" (the only alternative).

Comment: Now look at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_02 where it says "An ordinary character is an ERE that matches itself. An ordinary character is any character in the supported character set, except for the ERE special characters listed in ERE Special Characters. The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped <backslash> ( '\\' ) is undefined, except in the context of a bracket expression". So, `}` is an ordinary character and as such the interpretation of `\}` in this context is undefined.

Comment: I just googled the documentation for python's `re.escape()` and found https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html where it shows that whatever is it that python consideres a regexp, it's not a BRE or ERE as it contains constructs like `(?#...)`, `(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)`, and `(?P=name)`. I've no idea if it's PCRE or not, that page doesn't say.

Comment: Talking about PCRE `preg_quote('/}/')` returns `/\}/`

Comment: @EdMorton I was going to comment that `-E` is non-standard since the [the sed page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) doesn't mention it but the GNU sed manpage claims it **is** in POSIX, so now I'm confused. Ah: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310446/are-there-standard-versions-of-sed-on-which-e-is-unsupported

Comment: @jhnc yeah, my understanding is that, like any other POSIX feature, it'll be in a release of POSIX once it's been implemented in all `sed`s that claim to be POSIX conformant (POSIX documents common behavior rather than mandates common behavior). idk when that'll happen or which seds are involved.

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` code. Using `match` function where using regex `(^.*{)"(.*)"(}.*$)` which creates 3 capturing groups and saves its values into array named arr, if a true match found then simply printing all the values of array to get required output.

```
awk 'match($0,/(^.*{)"(.*)"(}.*$)/,arr){print arr[1] arr[2] arr[3]}' Input_file
```

Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k3JC33/1) for used regex.

***2nd solution:*** OR if you have same data as shown samples and you have `{"` and `"}` occurring only 1 time each line then try following.

```
awk '{sub(/{"/,"{");sub(/"}/,"}")} 1'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {"word5 'word6' "word7 word8" .word9"} -word10 (word11)
word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {"word5 'word6' word7 word8 .word9"} -word10 (word11)
word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {"word5 'word6' "word7 (word8)" .word9"} -word10 (word11)
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="\"|[^\"]*";OFS=""}{$2=$(NF-1)="";print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {word5 'word6' "word7 word8" .word9} -word10 (word11)
word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {word5 'word6' word7 word8 .word9} -word10 (word11)
word1 -word2 {word3} -word4 {word5 'word6' "word7 (word8)" .word9} -word10 (word11)
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is either single `"` or zero-or-more non-`"` and there should not be nothing added between field in output. Then for each line I set 2nd field (first `"`) and field before last field (last `"`) to empty string i.e. delete it. **Disclaimer** this solution assumes `"` is never 1st character and `"` is never last character of line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*